# Need example for sharing data between docker container and docker host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using `docker-compose` yml file as follows:

```
services:
  test_workers:
     ...
     volumes:
       - ./test_workers/src/test:/app/test_workers/tests
```

As I understood this should create reflection of data, if I change things in host it will be immediately reflected to the corresponding container's folder and vice versa.
So, I did changes to file in host's folder path `/test_workers/src/test`, and it didn't reflected into container.

Container is already up using the docker-compose up directive.
Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Please see [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3211) issue.

Comment: Where is your docker-compose.yml file comparing to host's folder that you want to mount with vm?

Comment: Is `/test_workers/src/test` absolute or relative path?